# how to get next 1000 records the fastest way

Tags: azure-storage

I'm using Azure Table Storage.
Let's say i have a Partition in my Table with 10,000 records, and I would like to get records number 1000 to 1999. And next time i would like to get records number 4000 to 4999 etc.
What is the fastest way of doing that?

All I can find till now are two options, which I don't like very much:
1. run a query which returns all 10,000 records, and filter out what I want when I get all 10,000 records.
2. Run a query whichs returns 1000 records at a time, and use a continuation token to get the next 1000 records.

Is it possible to get a continuation token without downloading all corresponding records? It would be great if i can get Continuation Token 1, than get Continuation token 2, and with CT2 get records 2000 to 2999.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you should be able to use continuation tokens without downloading the actual data for the first 1000 recors by closing the connection you have after the first request. And I mean closing it at TCP level. And before you read all data. Then open a new connection and use continuation token there. Two WebRequests will not do it since the HTTP implementation will likely use keep alive wchich means all your data is going to be read in the background even though you don't read it in your code. Actually you can configure your HTTP requests to not use keep alive.

However, another way is naturally if you know the RowKey and can search on that but I assume you don't know which row keys will be in each 1000 entity batch.

Last I would ask why you have this problem in the first place. ***And what your access pattern is***. If inserts are common and getting these records is rare I wouldn't bother making it more efficient. if this is like a paging problem i would probably get all data on the first request and cache it (in the cloud). if inserts are rare but you need to run this query often I would consider making the insertion of data have one partion for every 1000 entities and rebalance as needed (due to sorting) as entities are inserted.